# Resizing a sheet on Mac Catalyst with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I have a very simple application that displays a `sheet`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sheet: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("Sheet") {
            self.sheet.toggle()
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheet) {
            Text("Resize Me!")
        }
    }
}
```

I want the user to be able to resize the `sheet` while the app is running on the Mac via *Catalyst*. When hovering over the corner, the cursor changes to display the *two-headed arrow*, but the `sheet` cannot be resized (It does somehow resize by about `1px` or so).
Here is a [short video](https://vimeo.com/709042953), showcasing the issue.

Is there any way to make the sheet resizable by the user?

Comment: you can't resize a `sheet` you can create different sizes with a UIKit popover.